# How to get numbers format based on user location?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have these 2 values

```
1.230
```

That means in Italy one thousand and 230, if an American had to write that, would write

```
1,230
```

Currently using:

```
myValue.toLocaleString('it');
```

For US we should be using `myValue.toLocaleString('en-US');`

How would we detect the correct number format we should be displaying?

Comment: Related: [Javascript toFixed localized?](/q/2865719/4642212).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```
myValue.toLocaleString(navigator.language)
```

Comment: this looks super, I am wondering, will this detect browser language or what is it detetcing?

Comment: navigator.language gives  browser's language. For example it gives tr-TR for me  and when you run it will give for your browser language

Comment: ok but browser language isn't that correct, what if I am italian and I am in the us?

Comment: I just tried using opera browser and changing the VPN, it is still showing me the period format

Comment: Yes because it look your language preferences of browser. it is independent of your location.  for location it can be more complicated. you can get navigator.geolocation to get position but then you need to find country code from it then u can reach culture code.

Comment: Also if you use location , you need also permission from user to open its location detail

Comment: You can also use http://ip-api.com/json get country code then u need one array tthat includes country and language code then u can get it

Comment: @pc_coder I did read around in regards. I have one question about it, is that something that will always be online or it might get down? It looks like a private project so I am wondering how reliable is

Comment: Of course if there is a different url reliability is lower. And it has limit for usafe for free. So in my opinion using browser language is better. Because there could be a opposite scenerios. So I prefer to user's choice. If he or she wants to italian then change its language preference to italian, if wants american english change its language reference to english.

Comment: @pc_coder makes sense, I agree. I will accept this answer. But we know it's not 100% complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) as

```js
var number = 3500;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
```

Comment: how is this detecting the correct number format we should use, can you explain?

Comment: It looks at browser language settings too.